Other sentient beings on our planet
Humans are sure they're the peak of evolution, even though we evolved as top predators and still en mass treat the planet as if we're top predators even if we're not directly officially involved in the destruction.
Out thoughts are are our main blockages to enlightenment and being connected with something higher. So why are we so sure we're higher than the smart vegetarian animals like whale and elephants? Is it possible whales are floating around the ocean, not caught up in all the negative mindset we suffer, and actually already connected to higher planes of consciousness?

Is this a question about Buddhist doctrine or practice? If so it's not clear what aspect of Buddhist doctrine or practice you are asking about?

Obviously, there have been biological animals, including vegetarians, that have eaten their way to the extinction of their species. Biological animals, while having very limited scopes of behaviour, are generally driven by instinct, i.e., lust. Therefore, biological animals can destroy the environment that sustains them via over consumption.
In Buddhism, people/mortals (macce) are psychologically (not biologically) classified into six types: human, god (benevolent power), demons (violent power), animals (lacking moral conscience), hungry ghosts (addicts) & hell beings (acutely suffering people). In Buddhism, the term 'human' does not mean biological 'homo sapiens'.
The term 'human' ('manussa') in Buddhism etymologically means 'high minded'. The Pali scriptures define the 'human' as follows:

... the human state (manussattaṁ)... is... conduct guided by the Dhamma... righteous
conduct... wholesome activity... meritorious activity..  here
there [does not] prevails mutual devouring, the devouring of the weak... they
have... seen the Four Noble Truths. What four? The noble truth of
suffering … the noble truth of the way leading to the cessation of
suffering.
SN 56.11

Therefore, in Buddhism, the 'human state' is the highest state a person can develop.

@Dhmma Dhatu Is human state considered to be higher than gods?

@Kobamschitzo sfaik it's considered the state most propitious for enlightenment -- too high means (temporarily) no suffering, or even no senses with which to hear the dhamma.

the gods are lost in bliss & other preoccupations therefore the human state is the most favurable for enlightenment
